# Custom Workflow activity designer - Binding expressionTextBox in code

Tags: .net, data-binding, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-activity

I have a activity that I need to create, it contains two combo boxes that have the service that the activity is to call and then the method. Once the method is called I create a bunch of textboxes for the required parameters.

[image]

This works fine however I'm having problems databinding these dynamicaly created textboxes to the ModelItem for my activity

I see alot of stuff on-line about binding via xaml, but binding in code to ModelItem seems a bit sparse.

I appreciate any pointers!

Comment: I'm doing the same idea here ( reflectign methods ), and I end up using ModelItem properties for binding, I wonder if you manage a cleaner binding approach

Answer (score 0):

Rory Primrose did some work on implementing a Dependency Resolver in an activity in WF. He also deals with automatically generating the arguments on the designer and being able to bind to them. Maybe his series will be of help to you:
[Custom Windows Workflow activity for dependency resolution–Wrap up](http://www.neovolve.com/post/2010/10/01/Custom-Windows-Workflow-activity-for-dependency-resolutione28093Wrap-up.aspx)